# How to exclude IMAP-Folder in INBOX from reading with imap_open (PHP)

Tags: php, imap

I´m working on a script in PHP that reads all mails in INBOX, detects special mails via Header-Info and moves processed mails into a folder. I want to exclude this folder from further reading, at the moment my script also finds mails that are already in the processed folder. I´m using the imap_open function like this:

```
$host = "{" . HOST . ":" . PORT . "/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX";
$email = EMAIL;
$password = PASSWORD;
$imap = imap_open($host, $email, $password) or die("Cannot Connect " . imap_last_error());
$emailIds = imap_search($imap, 'FROM ' . SCAN_EMAIL_FOR_OFFERS, SE_UID);

if (!empty($emailIds)) {
    foreach ($emailIds as $emailId) {
        $email = new readMail();
        $header = $email->get_headerinfo($imap, $emailId);
        if (strpos($header->subject, "Angebot Nr.") != false) {
            ...Doing stuff...

            $email->move_mail($imap, $emailId, MOVE_PROCESSED_TO_FOLDER);
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "No new offers.";
}

imap_close($imap);
```

Regards

Edit: This is the move-func of readMail-Class...

```
function move_mail($imap, $uid, $inboxFolder) {
        $msgNo = imap_msgno($imap, $uid);
        $movingMail = imap_mail_move($imap, $msgNo, 'INBOX/'. $inboxFolder);
        if($movingMail == false) {die(imap_last_error());}
    }
```

Comment: Why not use CP_UID with imap_mail_move, rather than msgno?  You might want to try expunge to make sure the emails are deleted after moving.

Comment: Thx for your reply. I will consider this. I solved the upper problem by just selecting UNSEEN emails...